# Least value of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How to find the least possible value of $\frac{6a}{3b}+\frac{10b}{3a}$, where $a,b$ are positive real numbers?

Answer (score 8):

W/O using calculus,

as $a,b$ are positive real

$$\frac{\dfrac{6a}{3b}+\dfrac{10b}{3a}}2\ge\sqrt{\dfrac{6a}{3b}\cdot\dfrac{10b}{3a}}$$

Comment: Cool. Use "arithmetic mean is never less than geometric". Real cool!

Answer (score 4):

Put $x=a/b$ and reduce the problem to the minimization of a function of the single variable $x$: 
$$
f(x)=2x+\frac{10}{3x}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

To continue @Siminore's answer, you'll need to:

1. Calculate $f'(x)$ in order to find all the curve points:

   - $f'(x)=2-\frac{10}{3x^2}$
   - $f'(x)=0 \implies 2-\frac{10}{3x^2}=0 \implies x=\pm\sqrt\frac{5}{3}$
   - $a,b>0 \implies x>0 \implies x=\sqrt\frac{5}{3}$ is the only relevant curve point
2. Calculate $f''(x)$ in order to make sure that the curve point is a minimum point:

   - $f''(x)=\frac{20}{3x^3}$
   - $f''(\sqrt\frac{5}{3})=\frac{20}{3{\sqrt\frac{5}{3}}^3}>0 \implies x=\sqrt\frac{5}{3}$ is a minimum point for $f(x)$
3. Calculate the value of $f(x)$ at the minimum point in order to get an answer to your question:

   - $f(\sqrt\frac{5}{3})=2\sqrt\frac{5}{3}+\frac{10}{3\sqrt\frac{5}{3}}=\frac{20}{3\sqrt\frac{5}{3}}=\sqrt\frac{80}{3}$

---

Therefore, the least possible value of $\frac{6a}{3b}+\frac{10b}{3a}$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, is $\sqrt\frac{80}{3}$.

Comment: @Priya: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

To shorten it more combine both answers.
Write f(x) = 2x + 10/3x
Now Arithmetic mean is greater than equal to Geometric mean so 
(2x + 10/3x )/2 is greater than equal to (2x.10/3x)^1/2 
So 2x +10/3x has minimum value (80/3)^1/2